# Framework not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, linker

I know similar questions have been asked many time, but unfortunately none of those answers are able to solve my problem.

The problem is I got an new iMac recently and when I add any 3rd party framework (for eg: comScore)  drag/drop or using "Add framework" method,  it gives me compile error

```
ld: framework not found comScore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I created a test application, and has no other functionality. In that also it is throwing same error.

On my previous machine, and all other machines, It works just fine. this problem is only specific to this new mac.

Framework Search Paths for target and project has following values

```
$(inherited)

"$(SRCROOT)"

"$(SRCROOT)"/CStest/
```

The structure of folder in which all project files are like this:

```
CGTest (Outermost Folder Name)

  --> CGTest

  --> CGTest.xcodeproj
```

comScore.Framework is there inside CGTest folder.

Comment: Have you checked "Target Membership" via the Inspector pane for the library? Recent Xcode versions have required me to do this manually for items where project membership has been a result of drag & drop operations.

Comment: Adam: The "Target Membership" for framework is set to "required" and also check mark is checked. I believe that is not an issue.